# Android-how to supply open android camera permission by decoding and decompiling apk file

Tags: android, android-camera, apk, decode, decompiler

hi i create a apk file by turning wordpress website to mobile app using various wordpress plugin.wordpress website provide real time web conference. when ı convert wordpress site to mobile apk, android camera didnt open althougth in preview of mobile apk generator,camera is opened by android device.to fixing this problem,ı think that apk file  must be decoded and using  in manifest file of apk.
   how to supply open android camera permission by decoding and decompiling apk file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fo use the camera in an Android app you must add this to the manifiest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: when ı decompile the apk file with your suggestions ı take the error which seen attached file exception in thread main brut.androlib.AndrolibException:brut.directory.PathNotExist:apktool.yml